# What is the most common name for topological compactifications?

Tags: general-topology, definition, compactness, automorphism-group, compactification

**Definition:** Topological compactification is such compactification of a topological space such that all autohomeomorphisms on that space can be continuously extended into autohomeomorphisms of the compactification.

I have seen such compactifications called H-compactifications, Equivariant extenstions or G-compactifications (where G could be a subgroup of the group of all autohomeomorphisms of the studied space).

Which of this terms is the most used in your opinion?

Comment: The most used is perhaps the Alexandroff one-point compactification, because it is only "one" point, but this is probably "opinion-based".

Comment: @DietrichBurde I didnt ask for particular most used topological compactifications, but for which term is used for these compactifications. If I asked for the examples, I would also say Alexandroff, and also Stone-Čech are the two most common examples of topological compactifications.