# What does it mean that "compactification is defined only with respect to the topology of the base space"?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

I am reading about topological compactifications, one of the materials I came accross is [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266999999_Topological_compactifications) by Benjamin Vejnar.

**My question:**

What does it mean that *"the compactification is defined only
with respect to the topology of the base space and does not depend on the concrete representation of the space"?*
I dont know how interpret it. Maybe my problem is that I don't know how are compactifications and topological compactifications usually defined (I have seen construction of Stone-Čech and Alexandroff one-point compactifciation, but not many other examples). Thank you for any insights!

**Definition:** Topological compactification (or "H-compactification") is such compactification of a topological space such that all autohomeomorphisms on that space can be continuously extended into autohomeomorphisms of the compactification.

**Disclaimer:** "Topological compactification" is really NOT every compactification. I have already tried to explain this in a [different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246662/what-is-the-most-common-name-for-topological-compactifications) but didn't get any answer.

Comment: The other "question" wasn't really a question IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like many brief and cryptic sentences found in introductions of research papers, this "concrete representation" sentence is most likely intended to be an appeal to some kind of intuition which a less fortunate reader may not share. In this case, it is an appeal to an intuitive understanding of a broad class of compactification constructions.

There are many, many, many ways to construct compactifications by embedding $X$ into compact spaces: If $f : X \to C$ is any embedding of $X$ into a compact space $C$, meaning a homeomorphism from $X$ onto a subspace of $C$, then the closure of the image $\overline{\text{image}(f)}$ may be regarded as a compactification of $X$.

Let's take $X = (0,1]$ for example.

We could embed $f : (0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ by the formula
$$f(x) = (x,\sin(1/x))
$$
The subspace $\text{image}(f) \subset \mathbb R^2$ is bounded and is therefore contained in a closed ball, which is compact. The closure $\overline{\text{image}(f)}$ is therefore a compactification of $(0,1]$, known as the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) (or most of the topologist's sine curve, at least, including the most interesting portion of it). Notice that $\overline{\text{image}(f)}$ is obtained by adding a line segment to $\text{image}(f)$, namely $\{0\} \times [-1,+1]$.

Or we could choose a different embedding $f : (0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ using the formula
$$f(x) = (r(x) \cos(\theta(x)), r(x) \sin(\theta(x)))
$$
where $r(x)= 1 - x$ and $\theta(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Again $\text{image}(f)$ is bounded, which gives a compactification $\overline{\text{image}(f)}$ that is obtained from $\text{image}(f)$ by adding the unit circle to $\text{image}(f)$.

Now let your imagination run wild: by choosing "concrete representations" of the space $X = (0,1]$, for example representations as bounded subsets of a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, we obtain many, many strange compactifications of $X$.

What that sentence means, in a rather rough and intuitive sense, is this: an $H$-compactification is *not* one of these random, silly, "concrete representation" compactifications.

Answer (score 3):

The usual definition of a compactification $(Y,e)$ of a space $X$ is pair of a compact space $Y$ and a continuous $e: X \to Y$ so that $e[X]$ is dense in $Y$ and $e\restriction X \to e[X]$ is a homeomorphism.

Often we take $Y$ to be Hausdorff and stipulate $X$ to be non-compact to avoid some trivialities.

In practice we pretend $X \subseteq Y$ as a subspace (as $e$ is an embedding anyway) and $X$ is dense, and write $Y$ as $\gamma X$ or $\alpha X$ or $\beta X$ (if we have some construction of sorts to go from $X$ to $Y$).

Comment: To the proposer: To clarify the italicized quote in the Q, if $f:X'\to X$ is a homeomorphism, we call $X'$ a representation of $X$. And then $(Y, e\circ f)$ is a compactification of $X'.$